# How to read the variable value in AHK?

Tags: autohotkey

## I want AHK to do something, ONLY if a particular variable has a particular value.

Code:

```
<^<!/::
MsgBox,4,Timer,Do you want to set a timer?
IfMsgBox Yes
{
InputBox,Time1 , Timer, What hour? (Please show in 24:00 format)
InputBox,Time2,Timer, What minute?
IfTime1 := A_Hour, Time2 := A_Min
MsgBox,64,Timer,Timer done.
}
else{}
return
```

If you don‘t understand what i am trying to do, I‘m trying to set a timer.
What i want:
When I press ctrl+alt+/, I want an msgbox to open, asking to set a timer or not.
If I click on yes, I want two input boxes open one by one, in which i will write the time.
Next, when i am done setting the time, the input box will close. Now, The time in the input box will write to a variable named time and time2. Then, if the time1 is same as A_Hour and time2 is same as A_Min, An MsgBox will show up with an info icon.
What happens:
After setting the time, the msgbox with an info icon immediately shows up.

Can anyone correct the code above and send an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<^<!/::
    MsgBox,4,Timer,Do you want to set a timer?
    IfMsgBox Yes
    {
        InputBox, Time1, hour, What hour? (Please show in 24:00 format)
        if ErrorLevel ; CANCEL was pressed
            return
        if (Time1 > 23)
        {
            MsgBox, wrong hour specification
            return
        }
        InputBox,Time2, minute, What minute?
        if ErrorLevel
            return
        if (Time2 > 59)
        {
            MsgBox, wrong minute specification
            return
        }
        SetTimer, Timer, 1000 
    }
return

Timer:
    if (A_Hour = Time1 && A_Min = Time2)
    {
        SetTimer, Timer, off
        MsgBox,64,Timer,Timer done.
    }
return
```